# white-label collaborative open-source development (e.g. github/sourceforge/google-code in a box)?

Tags: open-source, github, google-code, sourceforge

Does anyone have a recommendation for an open-source or paid (either packaged or SaaS) solution for integrating collaborative development features into your own website?  Here's more details:

We currently host an online plugin gallery for our product. Users can upload and download plugins. But users can't easily collaborate on a plugin's development, can't easily report and track bugs on a plugin, can't easily track a plugin's versions or roadmap, etc.

Of course, contributors can host their plugin development on github, sourceforge, google code, codeplex, etc.  But keeping users on our website has some advantages. For example:

- We can use single-sign-on to avoid yet another username/password required
- we can integrate end-user issue tracking into our existing online issue-tracking systems
- we can get integrated analytics so we can better meet the needs of top contributors as well as downloaders
- We can easily reward reputation points to committers just like we do for people who answer lots of questions

Anyone know a good solution for white-label sites for open-source project developer collaboration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be [RedMine](http://redmine.org) or [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org); Trac would require you to set up a separate instance for each project (TracForge can, I believe, help with that).  Another option would be Gitorious (I believe its code is all open-source).

There's also GForge, but I wouldn't recommend it (its UI is like old-school SourceForge; I find that rather clunky).

Comment: Actually, GForge *is* old-school SourceForge.

Answer (score 2):

Atlassian Studio might be what you're after:

- Subversion - Source Control
- JIRA  -Issue tracking
- FishEye - Source Code Search
- Confluence - Enterprise Wiki
- Greenhopper - Agile Planning
- Bamboo - Continuous Integration
- Crucible - Peer Code Review

All hosted in the cloud, prices start at $125 for 5 developers.

http://www.atlassian.com/hosted/studio/

Alternatively for a cheaper alternative, Atlassian offer open source licenses which would allow you to use each of the above for free, however you'd need to host them yourself, and configure them to talk to each other manually (whereas Studio is a hosted SaaS environment with interoperability already configured out of the box).

If you don't qualify for an Open Source license, and you've got 10 developers or less, you can get a Starter License for every product except Crucible for $10 - full commercial license, with support etc.

(This isn't meant to be an ad for Atlassian, and I don't have any connection with them, I just love their products for this kind of solution).

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned GitHub and SourceForge:

- [GitHub:FI](http://FI.GitHub.Com/) is a white-label version of GitHub
- SourceForge used to be available as a white-label version at some point, I have no idea whether that is still true though (Hmm, it seems it is called [CollabNet TeamForge](http://WWW.Open.Collab.Net/products/ctf/) now)
- before that, SourceForge actually was Open Source up until version 3, and there exist multiple forks of the original software:

  - [Savane](http://Gna.Org/projects/savane/), a fork started by the GNU project, the software powering [GNU Savannah](http://Savannah.GNU.Org/) and [Gna!](http://Gna.Org/)
  - [GForge](http://GForge.Org/), a fork started by one of the SourceForge developers, the software powering [Alioth](http://Alioth.Debian.Org/) (until recently) and [RubyForge](http://RubyForge.Org/)

    - [FusionForge](http://FusionForge.Org/), a fork of GForge by three of the developers after the parent company took GForge proprietary, the software powering [Alioth](http://Alioth.Debian.Org/)

[Gitorious](http://Gitorious.Org/) is an open source competitor to GitHub. [Launchpad](https://Launchpad.Net/) is going to be released as open source sometime this year, and is also available or sale and/or rent right now, I believe. FogBugz launched [Kiln](http://FogCreek.Com/kiln/), a Mercurial hosting and code review service.